# Deep Learning SummationLayer does not support varying dimensions on Linux server

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying a recurrent network in Linux server using MMA 11.3. The network structure is as follows:

```
net = NetInitialize[
  NetGraph[
   <|
    "Conv" -> 
      NetMapOperator[
        NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[3, {3, 3}], FlattenLayer[]}, "Input" -> {5, 11, 11}]], 
    "LSTM1" -> LongShortTermMemoryLayer[40, "Dropout" -> 0.4], 
    "Dropout" -> DropoutLayer[0.3], 
    "Linear" -> NetMapOperator[LinearLayer[1]], "Ramp" -> Ramp, 
    "Sum" -> SummationLayer[]
   |>, 
   {NetPort["Circulation"] -> "Conv" -> "LSTM1" -> "Dropout" -> "Linear" -> "Ramp" 
       -> "Sum" -> NetPort["TotalPrecipitation"], 
    "Ramp" -> NetPort["HourlyPrecipitation"]}
  ]
]
```

It works for MMA 11.3 Macbook Pro. However, when I copied the code to the Linux server for training using GPU, it reports that:

> NetGraph::valfail: Validation failed for SummationLayer: Layer does not support varying dimensions.

Could anyone help?

Comment: P.S., I do need varying dimensions in the application.

Comment: Hypothesis: your mac has a newer NeuralNetworks paclet version, and this is only supported in the latest version. Try `Lookup[PacletInformation["NeuralNetworks"], "Version"]` on both machines. Just run `PacletUpdate["NeuralNetworks"]` on your Linux machine if older version.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is a bug, but since in the document of SummationLayer, we have:

```
r = RandomReal[1, {5, 3, 2}];
SummationLayer[][r] === AggregationLayer[Total, All][r]
```

Thus, by replacing SummationLayer with AggregationLayer[Total,All], the network could be initialized.